# JavaScript cycle through json string

Tags: javascript, json, string, loops

I've got the following JSON string:

```
{"index_name":"grafana1","begin":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","calculated_at":"2022-06-01T00:00:04.099Z","took_ms":0},{"index_name":"grafana2","begin":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","calculated_at":"2022-06-02T00:00:05.099Z","took_ms":0}
```

On my website (made with vanilla JavaScript) I'd like to display only the values of "index_name" and "calculated_at".

I'm looking for a way to cycle through the whole string lenght and for each entry show only the value of those two keys.

My website should be looking something like this:

```
grafana1
2022-06-01T00:00:04.099Z

grafana2
2022-06-02T00:00:05.099Z
```

Comment: What is stopping you from [looping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) through it and displaying the properties you wish to?

Comment: That’s not valid JS; is it actually in an array? What specific issue are you having?

Answer (score 0):

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  console.log(typeof value);
  if (key !== 'index_name') and (key !== 'calculated_at') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

let userStrReplacer = JSON.stringify(userObj, replacer);
console.log(userStrReplacer);
```